# How to show count of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data

```
   ReasonId   Team   Division Location
     2          A                 L1
     3          B        D1       L2
     2          A        D2       L1 
     2          A        D3       L3
```

I want to show the count grouped by the **ReasonId** for each team,division & location. There could be instances where division *could be null*.

I am trying something like this,

```
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalRequests, Reason, team
FROM
    reports
GROUP BY Reason , team
UNION SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalRequests, Reason, location
FROM
    reports
GROUP BY Reason , location 
UNION SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalRequests, Reason, division
FROM
    reports
WHERE
    ISNULL(division) = 0
GROUP BY Reason , division
;
```

The output I am getting for the above is,

```
   TotalRequests    Reason  team
        1             2 
        3             2      A
        1             3      B
        1             3     D1
        1             2     D2
        1             2     D3
        2             2     L1
        1             3     L2
        1             2     L3
```

Is it possible to get an output that looks like this,

```
ReasonId   Team  TotalByTeam   Location TotalByLocation  Division TotalByDivision
  2         A       3             L1          2                          0
  2         A       3             L3          1              D2          1
  2         A       3             L3          1              D3          1
  3         B       1             L2          1              D1          1
```

I am using **mysql 8.0.17** [Here's a sample schema and dbfiddle of same](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bc61381d22a0a377d2c1b10e75155b0)

```
CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `Reason` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Team` text,
  `Division` text,
  `Location` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



    INSERT INTO reports (Reason,Team,Division,Location) values (2,  'A',null,'L1');
    INSERT INTO reports (Reason,Team,Division,Location) values (3,  'A','D1','L2');
    INSERT INTO reports (Reason,Team,Division,Location) values (2,  'A','D2','L1');
    INSERT INTO reports (Reason,Team,Division,Location) values (2,  'A','D3','L3');
```

Comment: @Strawberry Added a dbfiddle link. Am i missing anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use analytic functions `COUNT(...) OVER (...)` for this. They are available in MySQL since version 8.0.

```
select
  reasonid,
  team,
  count(team) over (partition by team) as total_by_team,
  location,
  count(location) over (partition by location) as total_by_location,
  division,
  count(division) over (partition by division) as total_by_division
from reports;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79891554331e8222041ec34eea3fc4ee

Comment: You should use `count(division)` instead of `count(*)` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6572ee4352ad0bec6677c92c41571ef4

Comment: @Radim Bača: Yes, thank you. I didn't see that the column can be null. As I don't know about the others, I've used the same on team and location now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below script-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d221fbc60fdecff4451c0ca07b0e9a43)

```
SELECT A.ReasonId,
A.Team,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table B WHERE B.ReasonId = A.ReasonId AND B.Team = A.Team) TotalByTeam,
A.Division,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table B WHERE B.ReasonId = A.ReasonId AND B.Division = A.Division) TotalByDivision,
A.Location,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table B WHERE B.ReasonId = A.ReasonId AND B.Location = A.Location) TotalByLocation
FROM your_table A
```

Comment: The sample data provided here is just a snapshot. What if I have hundreds of records. DoI have to manually add the UNION ALL for each row of data. That would not be ideal

Comment: @Ayubx: No. `WITH your_table(ReasonId,Team,Division,Location) AS (...)` is just for the demonstration. In reality you *have* a table and hence don't have to create one on-the fly. Just use the query starting with `SELECT A.ReasonId,` and change `FROM your_table` to `FROM reports`. Or better even, use my query ;-)

Comment: @Ayubx, no. You can just ignore the first part of the script as Thorsten mentioned. I missed your point initially. I have created a the your_table just for demonstration using CTE. Editing the answer by removing CTE part for erasing your confusion.